# M1 earphone jack intermittently not recognised

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, apple-silicon

The earphone jack on my M1 Macbook Air goes through periods of working and not working (i.e. just not recognising that earphones are plugged in). It seems that it's more likely to work if I haven't plugged them in for a while, besides that I really have no idea why it works sometimes and not others. Has anyone seen this issue or have some idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the port or use different earphones (to help determine where the problem lies)?

Comment: @fsb yes I've tried both of those, it's definitely the jack and not the earphones

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is having the same problem - I took it to an Apple store and it turned out to be an issue with the logic board (it's not causing any other issues besides the headphone jack that I'm aware of).